# ¿Cómo obtener los valores de celdas en tabla HTML con JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-tabla

Tengo una tabla HTML  y necesitó crear una función que la recorra y obtenga los valores  de las celdas de cada fila.

Cada celda contiene su respectivo ID.

Mi código HTML:

```
<table id="tablaLineas" class="display compact dt-center table table-striped table-light" style="width:100%">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="display:none;">Nº</th>
                        <th>Article</th>
                        <th>Unit</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Subtotal</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    </tr><tr id="r0">
                  <td style="display:none;"> 0 </td>
                  <td id="r10"> TV </td>
                  <td id="r20"> UNIT </td>
                  <td id="r30"> Descripcion TV </td>
                  <td id="r40"> 23 </td>
                  <td id="r50"> 2 </td>
                  <td id="r60"> 46 </td>
                  <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="RemoveLinea(0)"><small><i class="mdi mdi-delete-forever"></i></small></a></td>
                  </tr><tr id="r1">
                  <td style="display:none;"> 1 </td>
                  <td id="r11"> Laptop </td>
                  <td id="r21"> UNIT </td>
                  <td id="r31"> Descripcion laptop </td>
                  <td id="r41"> 10 </td>
                  <td id="r51"> 5 </td>
                  <td id="r61"> 50 </td>
                  <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="RemoveLinea(1)"><small><i class="mdi mdi-delete-forever"></i></small></a></td>
                  </tr><tr id="r2">
                  <td style="display:none;"> 2 </td>
                  <td id="r12"> Telefono </td>
                  <td id="r22"> UNIT </td>
                  <td id="r32"> Descripcion laptop </td>
                  <td id="r42"> 3 </td>
                  <td id="r52"> 20 </td>
                  <td id="r62"> 60 </td>
                  <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="RemoveLinea(2)"><small><i class="mdi mdi-delete-forever"></i></small></a></td>
                  </tr><tr id="r3">
                  <td style="display:none;"> 3 </td>
                  <td id="r13"> Memoria </td>
                  <td id="r23"> UNIT </td>
                  <td id="r33"> Descripcion Memora </td>
                  <td id="r43"> 15 </td>
                  <td id="r53"> 3 </td>
                  <td id="r63"> 45 </td>
                  <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="RemoveLinea(3)"><small><i class="mdi mdi-delete-forever"></i></small></a></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obtener los elementos de todas las celdas puedes seleccionar todos los `td` y agregarlos en un `arreglo` y seleccionar su contenido con `text()`.

```
let items = []
$('td').each( function(){
   if( $(this).attr('id'))
   items.push( $(this).text() );       
});
```

Si quieres crear un arreglo por cada fila, puedes hacer:

```
const porFila = [];
while(items.length)
  porFila.push(items.splice(0,6));
```

Te adjunto un ejemplo funcional:

```js
let items = []
let itemObj = {}
$('td').each( function(){
   if( $(this).attr('id')){
    items.push( $(this).text());
    
    //Alternativamente con creando un Objeto
    itemObj[ $(this).attr('id')] = $(this).text()
    }       
});
console.log(items)
console.log(itemObj)


const porFila = [];
while(items.length)
  porFila.push(items.splice(0,6));
  
console.log(porFila)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tablaLineas" class="display compact dt-center table table-striped table-light" style="width:100%">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="display:none;">Nº</th>
                        <th>Article</th>
                        <th>Unit</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Subtotal</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    </tr><tr id="r0">
                  <td style="display:none;"> 0 </td>
                  <td id="r10"> TV </td>
                  <td id="r20"> UNIT </td>
                  <td id="r30"> Descripcion TV </td>
                  <td id="r40"> 23 </td>
                  <td id="r50"> 2 </td>
                  <td id="r60"> 46 </td>
                  <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="RemoveLinea(0)"><small><i class="mdi mdi-delete-forever"></i></small></a></td>
                  </tr><tr id="r1">
                  <td style="display:none;"> 1 </td>
                  <td id="r11"> Laptop </td>
                  <td id="r21"> UNIT </td>
                  <td id="r31"> Descripcion laptop </td>
                  <td id="r41"> 10 </td>
                  <td id="r51"> 5 </td>
                  <td id="r61"> 50 </td>
                  <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="RemoveLinea(1)"><small><i class="mdi mdi-delete-forever"></i></small></a></td>
                  </tr><tr id="r2">
                  <td style="display:none;"> 2 </td>
                  <td id="r12"> Telefono </td>
                  <td id="r22"> UNIT </td>
                  <td id="r32"> Descripcion laptop </td>
                  <td id="r42"> 3 </td>
                  <td id="r52"> 20 </td>
                  <td id="r62"> 60 </td>
                  <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="RemoveLinea(2)"><small><i class="mdi mdi-delete-forever"></i></small></a></td>
                  </tr><tr id="r3">
                  <td style="display:none;"> 3 </td>
                  <td id="r13"> Memoria </td>
                  <td id="r23"> UNIT </td>
                  <td id="r33"> Descripcion Memora </td>
                  <td id="r43"> 15 </td>
                  <td id="r53"> 3 </td>
                  <td id="r63"> 45 </td>
                  <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="RemoveLinea(3)"><small><i class="mdi mdi-delete-forever"></i></small></a></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Finalmente puedes acceder a cada elemento del array por fila como `porFila[0][0]`,  `porFila[1][2]`, etc. Ten en cuenta que el id que estás usando numera las filas empezando en 0 y las columnas empezando en 1, por lo que la indexación no será exactamente como el `id`.